# how do i create a linebreak in an inline math formula?

Tags: math-mode, equations, line-breaking, inline

I tried to make a equation in Latex but the parentheses disappear near the edge of the page. How I put the equation in two lines?

[image]

```
$\left(\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\int_{0}^{\dot{\theta}}
d(\dot{\theta}) ; \omega^2=\int_{0}^{\dot{\theta}}d(\dot{\theta}^2)
\right)$ varia de 0 at\'{e} $\dot{\theta}:$
```

Comment: Please **don't** add code as an image, but rather include it in the question (copy-paste). Also, it is rather impossible for us to know _how_ you have done things without you including and [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/30280).

Comment: @hooy I cannot add the image in this pc because the pc doesn't wanna send the image. I wanna put the links of the dropbox:

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vum59sdy5s775vq/Captura%20de%20ecr%C3%A3%202016-03-30%2C%20%C3%A0s%2011.18.41.png?dl=0

Comment: There are _many_ examples of multiline equations on this site including many of the links in the "related"  list on the right. Try the answers here for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267342/how-to-divide-this-equation-into-two-lines?rq=1

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/517q064kbwscl26/Captura%20de%20ecr%C3%A3%202016-03-30%2C%20%C3%A0s%2011.18.32.png?dl=0

Comment: @David Carlisle I wanna know in my code what I'm doing wrong. I don't wanna use packages or complicate formulas. But I have to give the report to my teacher and the parentheses disappear. If they disappear I will have a fail on this work.

Comment: The code you show should have `...$; $\omega^2...`

Comment: If you want someone to see your code you should add it as text to the question (I did not follow the dropbox links) But _any_ math in latex should use `amsmath` package, just as you use `article` or some other class if you need titles or sections.

Comment: @egreg I do that but gives me error too. There has to be another way.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález I'm sure you're able to *write* your current code in your original question. You should definitely take a look at the [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) before posting more questions to this site. You should almost always provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)! Proper questions get proper answers :-)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of copying the two screenshots you posted to Dropbox to the body of your posting. I've also added two tags and edited the title of your posting to clarify your objective.

Answer (score 5):

Judging by the screenshots you've posted, the culprit is the ill-advised use of `\left(` and `\right)` in the inline math formula. Material inside a `\left( ... \right)` construct is *never* broken across lines. *Never, ever*. If you need to enlarge the opening and closing parentheses of the inline formula, use `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)` instead.

As proof, consider the following screenshot and associated LaTeX code. It shows that **zero** line break possibilities are available if `\left( ... \right)` is used in the formula. In contrast, TeX finds **four** such possibilities if `\Bigl( ... \Bigr)` is used. I leave it to you to decide which method you should be using.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % looks like you're using a Palatino font
\setlength\textwidth{1mm} % choose an extremely narrow measure
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\mbox{\emph{With} \texttt{\string\left} and \texttt{\string\right}: 
\textbf{zero} linebreak possibilities in the formula}


\medskip
$\left(\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}=
\int_0^{\dot{\theta}} d(\dot{\theta});\allowbreak 
\omega^2=\int_{0}^{\dot{\theta}}d(\dot{\theta}^2) \right)$

\bigskip
\mbox{\emph{Without} \texttt{\string\left} and \texttt{\string\right}: 
\textbf{four} [!] linebreak possibilities}

\medskip
$\Bigl(\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}=
\int_0^{\dot{\theta}} d(\dot{\theta});\allowbreak 
\omega^2=\int_{0}^{\dot{\theta}}d(\dot{\theta}^2) \Bigr)$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problematic text seems to be like a parenthetical remark rather than a single formula. I'd avoid enlarged parentheses (solution A), but it's possible to get them as shown in solution B.

My preferred way would be avoiding the parentheses altogether (thanks to Paulo Cereda for help with Portuguese).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\begin{document}

\subsection{A}

A qual pode ser integrada para ângulos de $\theta_0$ a 
$\theta$ enquanto a velocidade angular
($\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\int_{0}^{\dot{\theta}}d(\dot{\theta})$;
$\omega^2=\int_{0}^{\dot{\theta}}d(\dot{\theta}^{2})$)
varia de $0$ até $\theta$:

\subsection{B}

A qual pode ser integrada para ângulos de $\theta_0$ a 
$\theta$ enquanto a velocidade angular
$\Bigl(\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\int_{0}^{\dot{\theta}}d(\dot{\theta})$;
$\omega^2=\int_{0}^{\dot{\theta}}d(\dot{\theta}^{2})\Bigr)$
varia de $0$ até $\theta$:

\subsection{C}

A qual pode ser integrada para ângulos de $\theta_0$ a 
$\theta$ enquanto a velocidade angular, com
$\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\int_{0}^{\dot{\theta}}d(\dot{\theta})$ e
$\omega^2=\int_{0}^{\dot{\theta}}d(\dot{\theta}^{2})$,
varia de $0$ até $\theta$:

\end{document}
```

[image]